# Get start time and end time of a employee work shift in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains clock in and out for employee attendance , and its structure is like this:

Note `InOut` 0 it means clock in and 1 is clock out.

```
EmployeeID LogDate  LogTime  TerminalID InOut
150157    1/1/2017  15:44:44    50054   0
150157    1/1/2017  19:53:01    50054   1
150157    1/1/2017  19:53:12    50054   1
150157    1/2/2017  10:40:59    50039   0
150157    1/2/2017  15:59:23    50058   0
150157    1/2/2017  21:01:50    50058   1
```

What I need is to get the start time and end time of a work shift in each day. According to the data in table, the result should be

```
Date        Start    End    Total Hours
1/1/2017    15:44    19:53   4:09
1/2/2017    10:40    21:01   10:21
```

Comment: Use Group By Clause.

Comment: What is the type of the `LogTime` column and why are you storing date and time separately?

Comment: So same guy managed to log out of same terminal twice in succession? This data structure WILL cause you a headache if it has errors like this. Any answer will be relying on login/out occurring in sequence, if you have one person doing login, logout, logout on one terminal, and leaving themselves logged in on another terminal forever, you can sorta forget having a nice "logged in/out" report

Comment: use min-max as an aggregation function and goup by employeeid and logdate

Comment: alexey; can't do that (well, you can.. but..), what if person a logs in at 9am for 1 mintuethen logs out, then logs in at 4:59 and logs out a minute later; your min(login) to max(logout) says they worked 8 hours, when they did 2 minutes! Logins and outs must be sorted, paired up, the time difference worked out, and then the differences summed. This data is full of errors that prevent that

Comment: That is a real world data structure. In the real world, data is dirty and people forget to clock on / off and clock off twice. It definitely happens

Comment: Agreed, though I think i'd at least have make time_in and time_out in the same row, then it's easier to see who forgot to clock out; at midnight on day 2, `UPDATE table SET time_out = 23:59 WHERE time_out is null`...

Comment: .. and if they previously clocked in twice without a clockout, you have two rows with NULL that will be updated. Yes, more sophisticated algorithms can be applied to clean this stuff up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of Alexey R's logic. Note that while it fits your example result, you'd never want to use it commercially, because it cannot cope with your broken data. It takes the first instance of any login by any employee anywhere, and makes that the firstlogin of the day. It does the same for the last logout by any emp, any terminal. If there is no first login/last logout it subs 00:00 and 23:59 respectively. It then defines a working shift as the difference between the two times. Danger danger: there's no guarantee that anyone did anything like the work hours reported:

```
SELECT
  LogDate,
  CONCAT(DATEDIFF(minute, firstlogin, lastlogout)/60, ':',DATEDIFF(minute, firstlogin, lastlogout)% 60) as total_hours
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      LogDate, 
      CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN InOut = 0 THEN LogTime END), '00:00:00'), 108) as FirstLogin, 
      CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN InOut = 1 THEN LogTime END), '23:59:59'), 108) as LastLogout
    FROM table
    GROUP BY logdate
  ) a
```

Comment: Fixed a typo in the hours calc logic

Comment: Please do heed the point WalkingLoreSuit made with his SQL; from your title text it looks like you want a report that is per employee per day, but your desired output example drops the "per employee" part. If you want per-employee, merge his SQL group by into mine

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the login time in minutes, look up how to convert minutes to HH:MM:SS. You will also run into trouble with this if the Employee doesn't have a log in and a log out on each date.

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID
    , LogDate
    , MIN(CASE WHEN inout = 0 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END) AS Start
    , MAX(CASE WHEN InOut = 1 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END) AS End
    , DATEDIFF(n,  MIN(CASE WHEN inout = 0 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END), MAX(CASE WHEN InOut = 1 THEN LogTime ELSE NULL END))
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID, LogDate
```

Comment: Technically, this doesn't produce a result set that meets the spec

Comment: It's being used for employee attendance, any solution which doesn't also group by the employee ID will give him his desired output, but would also fail to give him what he requested in text. Hopefully he got some use out of it.

Comment: Yers, I too wrangle with the "what they say they want" vs "what it looks like they/i think they want" >> https://www.tamingdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/tree-swing-project-management-large.png I upvote your answer to acknowledge the method of making it per-employee